# Website performance sluggish - High CPU and Disk Usage

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, postgresql, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

Over the past couple of days my website's performance has been very sluggish, with queries taking a lot of time to execute. My CPU usage hit around 100% 4 times this week. Here is the output of `top` at one such time

```
top - 00:08:03 up 3 days, 21:47,  2 users,  load average: 6.06, 1.95, 0.84
Tasks:  92 total,   2 running,  90 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 86.1 us, 12.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  1.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1017948 total,   773520 used,   244428 free,   107200 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   257228 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
28433 www-data  20   0  854660  69288   5608 S 98.7  6.8   0:47.36 apache2
28469 www-data  20   0  529692   7692   3012 S  0.7  0.8   0:00.13 apache2
28514 root      20   0   24820   1488   1064 R  0.7  0.1   0:00.08 top
   25 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.3  0.0   1:00.70 kworker/0:1
28518 postgres  20   0  370016   6984   4276 S  0.3  0.7   0:00.01 postgres
    1 root      20   0   33384   1288      0 S  0.0  0.1   0:11.70 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.13 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:09.40 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:45.06 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  0.0  0.0   1:54.47 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
```

Apache seems to be taking up a lot of CPU but I have no idea why. It was working perfectly up until a couple of days ago. I've optimized Apache by removing unused modules, tuned it to only have a small number of spare children running but that doesn't seem to have made a difference. I've also installed `mod-evasive` and `mod-qos` to protect against DDOS. Here is my apache configuration

```
Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareServers       1
    MaxSpareServers       3
    MaxClients           10
    MaxRequestsPerChild 3000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareThreads       5
    MaxSpareThreads      15 
    ThreadLimit          25
    ThreadsPerChild       5
    MaxClients           25
    MaxRequestsPerChild 200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareThreads       5
    MaxSpareThreads      15 
    ThreadLimit          25
    ThreadsPerChild       5
    MaxClients           25
    MaxRequestsPerChild 200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_spamhaus.c>
    MS_METHODS POST,PUT,OPTIONS,CONNECT 
    MS_WhiteList /etc/spamhaus.wl 
    MS_CacheSize 256 
</IfModule>
```

Here is my VirtualHost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com$1 [last,redirect=301]

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess example python-path=/home/abc/example:/home/abc/example/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/abc/example/wsgi.py

    DocumentRoot /home/abc/example

    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /home/abc/example/static/

    <Directory /home/abc/example/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /home/abc/example/media/

    <Directory /home/abc/example/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js|json)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/javascript          js
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz 
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
</Ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</Ifmodule>
```

I'm using memcached to cache most of the queries. Web pages with few basic queries are faster (still not as fast as before though) while pages with complex queries take a lot of time. The server response time for such pages has increased from 0.2 seconds to 4 seconds (measured using Google PageSpeed Insights).

I'm using a PostgreSQL 9.3 database. Following is my postgresql.conf tuned using PgTune.

```
default_statistics_target = 50
maintenance_work_mem = 60MB
constraint_exclusion = on
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 704MB
work_mem = 6MB
wal_buffers = 8MB
checkpoint_segments = 16
shared_buffers = 240MB
max_connections = 80
```

Here is the graph of CPU, Disk and Bandwidth usage over the past month

[image: Monthly CPU Usage]
[image: Monthly Disk Usage]
[image: Monthly Bandwidth Usage]

Though the bandwidth shows an increase in the past week or so, but the actual traffic hasn't increased. I am getting an average of 1500 visitors per day for the past 15-20 days. The increased bandwidth usage could probably be an increase in bot activity.

My website is a Django application hosted on droplet with the configuration - 1GB Ram, 30GB SSD Disk, Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I have tried every possible thing I could think and cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong here. I am not very good at handling servers and the only thing I can think of now is to switch from Apache to nginx and from PostgreSQL to MySQL. Any suggestions that can help me figure out how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch to nginx makes sense, switch to mysql not so much

Comment: I am just guessing, but to me your memory usage and postgres config look suspicious. You have just 1G of Memory (which is not really a lot), but are allocating more then that for postgres buffers. Also, postgres seems not be using that memory (just .7%). Have you restarted postgres after tuning it? Bevor you do so however, make sure to decrease buffer sizes or upgrade your RAM. nginx is defiantly faster then Apache, but I have a feeling this will not solve your current problem.

Comment: @Isaac I did restart postgres. I tried upgrading my RAM to 4GB and that still did not solve the problem. What do you suggest should the buffer size be?

Comment: Sorry, I am not much of a db expert ... just some more general considerations: your tag suggests you are using apache 2.2 ... which is rather dated. You could try the general apache tuning tips at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html. But in order to really speed things up, you will need to understand exactly what is going on, why you get theses cpu spikes. I know that this comment won't help much, but it's all I can give you :(

Comment: While there's a lot of obvious issues here, the one which stands out is the last graph - why is your inbound bandwidth greater than the outbound? (and BTW upgrading your version of Apache is NOT going to help)

Answer (score 0):

Removing unused modules sometimes has the opposite effect as the server is then not able to cache effectively for example, but assuming this is not the problem, the other issue I think might be happening is that you may be low on memory and therefore the so called "disk thrashing" (high IO) occurs, this is very possible specially on a virtual host. A neighbour on that same virtual host might have released a new site which takes a bigger slice on memory leaving you with less. Also, look at the analytics data to find out why the sudden spike in traffic and where is it coming from.

Comment: How can I solve the issue of disk thrashing? I tried upgrading my RAM but that did not make a difference.

Comment: What disk thrashing? (0.0 wa / KiB Swap: 0 total / 1017948 total,   773520 used) This system has enough memory.